# boost shared_ptr operator =

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Here is code example

```
class A{
  int i;
public:
  A(int i) : i(i) {}
  void f() { prn(i); }
};

int main()
{
  A* pi = new A(9);
  A* pi2= new A(87);
  boost::shared_ptr<A> spi(pi);
  boost::shared_ptr<A> spi2(pi2);
  spi=spi2;
  spi->f();
  spi2->f();
  pi->f();
  pi2->f();
}
```

output:

```
87
87
0
87
```

The question is why is 0 in the output?

Note from documentation: Effects: Equivalent to shared_ptr(r).swap(*this).

But if `shared_ptr` objects just swapped, the result should be 9. And if the first object is deleted, there should be Segmentation fault.

So why 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay careful attention to what is being swapped:

```
shared_ptr(r).swap(*this)
// ^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's a *temporary* object constructed from `r`. The temporary goes out of scope immediately and dies, with whichever effects this has on the owned resource. Since in your code `spi` was the only owner of `*spi`, the object is deleted, and your subsequent access of `pi->f()` is simply undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

`pi` has been deleted. Accessing a member of a deleted object is undefined behavior; you could get 0, some other value, or a segmentation fault.

Comment: Or it might eat your dog and set your house on fire. All bets are off with code invoking UB.

Answer (score 1):

> So why 0?

So anything!

Assigning a new value to `spi` will delete the previous object it is pointing to. The makes `pi` a dangling pointer that cannot be used anymore. Calling `pi->f()` is undefined behaviour and can have any result.

Answer (score 1):

`pi` object is deleted after `spi = spi2` and who know what your runtime does for freed memory. For me it prints -572662307 in Debug and 1315904 in Release.